# Usb monitor as main display on Mac mini

Tags: display, mac-mini

Good day I am planning on buying the Mac mini m2 and I have a ASUS mb168b portable monitor with usb Type A not Type C.

I wanted to know is it possible to to use it as main monitor. Thanks

Comment: If you can use it as a a display, then you can also use it as the main display. Can you pls clarify your question?

Comment: @Alper The monitor uses a driver to connect so does it start up when it is switched on or do you have to log in first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to know is it possible to to use it as main monitor.

This appears to be a [Catch-22](https://www.bing.com/search?q=catch%2022%20meaning&pc=MOZL&form=MOZWSB) as you need a special driver for this monitor to work on macOS but to get the driver, you’ll need to download it which ostensibly requires you to use a monitor to get to their site to download and install it.

**Ultimately, you can use it as a main monitor, but I highly recommend that you don’t**. Aside from installation hurdles you also have to deal with:

- Boot time availability
- Recovery Mode
- Safe Mode
- Single User Mode
- Updates

Every of the above scenarios would render this display useless as the driver would not be loaded requiring you to get a proper monitor. The moment you need to invoke any of these modes/environments, you’re essentially dead in the water.

Comment: thank you I will have to get a proper monitor then.